# Commerce Price: Hide formatted amount if empty

Tags: views, commerce

I have a view with a regular commerce price and a discounted one. When using the Raw amounts everything works fine but when I use the formatted ones the hide if empty, Count the number 0 as empty and Hide rewrite if empty even though they are checked the amount of 0,00€ is shown!

What can I do to hide it?

Comment: Are you using this module to display the discounted price? http://drupal.org/project/commerce_extra_price_formatters

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting this question, I'm having the same issue right now.

Would you possibly know if this would correspond to any issue/ticket already tracked in the Commerce project?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed in Drupal commerce, but until it gets fixed you could add a custom template file to your theme. Copy `/sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-view-fields.tpl.php` to `/sites/all/themes/[YOUR_THEME]/templates/views-view-fields--[YOUR_PRODUCT_TYPE].tpl.php` and edit it.
Add something like: `<?php if($id == 'commerce_price' && empty($row->commerce_price)) continue; ?>` to your template file.

```
<?php foreach ($fields as $id => $field): ?>
  <?php if($id == 'commerce_price' && empty($row->commerce_price)) continue; ?>
  <?php if (!empty($field->separator)): ?>
```

...

Answer (score 0):

```
function MODULENAME_field_attach_view_alter(&$output, $context) {
 /*Remove price if null or has value 0.00*/
    if($context['display']['module'] == 'commerce_price'){
     $field_name = array_keys($output);
       if(!empty($field_name[0])){
            $field_name = $field_name[0];
            if(empty($output[$field_name]['#items'][0]['amount']))
                $output = array();
        }


    }
```

}